# Registering as iPhone Developer

Tags: iphone

tried to register myself as iPhone Developer. I have already an iTunes Account.

Got to this page: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#
but dont know what to do next. I dont want to download anything at the moment. Do I have to? Is the registration process completed now and they will take the money from my credit card?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps. You can sign up as an developer, that gives you access to all the API documentation, XCore etc. That doesn't cost you anything. You can then start developing and test the app on the simulator. 
If you want to test the application on an iPhone and then distribute it via the AppStore you will have to sign up to the iPhone Deveoper Program (and that costs $99).

Hope that helped.